# Firebase環境構築でTypeError: Cannot read property 'apps' of undefinedと出る

Tags: firebase, next.js

NextとTypescriptでWebサイトを作っています。
Firebaseを導入しようと思い `yarn add firebase` でFirebaseをインストールしNextに組み込もうとした際、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apps' of undefined
```

lib/firebase.tsとしてFirebaseの設定ファイルを作っています。

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/analytics'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  const firebaseConfig = {
    〜〜〜〜
  }

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  firebase.analytics()
}
```

**試したこと**
バージョン 7 以前は `import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'` のようにして import する必要があるとのことなので（[firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#version_800_-_october_26_2020))、`@import firebase from 〜` の部分を変えたら以下のようにエラーが変わりました

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

どうかよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firebase SDKのバージョンが9以上ではないですか？
9以上の場合は、初期化の方法が変わっているみたいです。
https://lupas.medium.com/firebase-9-beta-nuxt-js-981cf3dac910

ご参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます！